.Net MAUI Community Toolkit MediaElement not working inside a CarouselView on iOS
I am building an app with a content scroller similar to how Instagram does theirs. I would like video content to scroll with a swipe up/down. After some research, the CarouselView seemed to be the easiest implementation for this. It works perfectly on Android, but iOS just shows a blank screen. Even if I add a label in a VerticalStackLayout with the MediaElement nothing shows.
Below is the minimal code:
    <CarouselView
        IsBounceEnabled="False"
        IsScrollAnimated="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MediaList}"
        Loop="False">

        <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout
                Orientation="Vertical"
                SnapPointsAlignment="Start"
                SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" />
        </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="domain:MediaScrollerVM">

                <toolkit:MediaElement
                    x:Name="ContentMediaElement"
                    ShouldAutoPlay="True"
                    ShouldLoopPlayback="True"
                    ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
                    Source="{Binding MediaItem.ContentUrl}">
                </toolkit:MediaElement>

            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>

This is what I have tried:

In the full version there is an image component, a text title component, and a description with a LIKE and COMMENT button including a bottomsheet that loads.  I have removed ALL of this to test the bare minimum for iOS and it still will not load. As mentioned above, Android works fine with both this minimal test and with all items included.
I have added events to both the CurrentItemChanged and Scrolled events.  These fire with each scroll to next or previous item on Android, but nothing on iOS.  So not only is it not showing the content, it appears to not even be recognizing it as something to swipe through.
I also tried with just a label, and the label does not show either. Event with static content.
I tried adding a static source to the MediaElement, and still no luck.
Have also searched for solutions/"hacks"/workarounds and not a ton is available.  A few people with issues using MediaElement in other collection-type components, but not specifically CarouselView.

I feel I have tried everything short of using another component instead of CarouselView.  CollectionView seems like it would be a challenge with determining exactly where the scroll points are, and I have had a great deal of difficulty working with CollectionView and iOS with scrolling in another project.
In addition, this also does not work in DEBUG -or- RELEASE builds. We have had many cases where things magically disappear in RELEASE builds that worked fine in DEBUG.

Is there any log about this problem? And how can we reproduce this problem on our side? Could you please post the steps of reproduce this problem?

You can try to update the nugets of your app to the latest ones and try again. And I found a similar issue about this problem, you can check it here: BUG FIX: Fix MediaElement within Carousel Crash.
